# How do you change a variable outside of using operators like -- or ++?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner trying to add variables to each other in Unity, with C#. I'm trying to create a stock market simulator that allows you to buy stocks with a preset amount of money.

This is the truncated version of the code. It's my first time trying to edit or change a variable, and so far `++` or `--` does fine in changing my variable by a single digit, but I want to subtract my variable by another variable.

```cs
/* this triggers when you buy a share, adding to your amount of shares 
   and subtracting a sum from your bank */

public void BuyGE()
{
    GE.GEstockamount++;
    Market.Bank - GE.Price;  /* this line is the one causing me trouble */
}
```

Comment: You might be looking for `-=` and `+=`. (`a--` is equivalent to `a = a - 1` and `a -= b` is equivalent to `a = a - b`). The line that is giving you trouble doesn't contain an assignment so the new value is calculated but not used. You probably meant to write `Market.Bank = Market.Bank - GE.Price` or simply `Market.Bank -= GE.Price`

Comment: You may need to start a C# course before you can start working on any project. OR you can start the C# course and work on the project at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking to do is set your variable to the result of a mathematical operation. In C# (and most programming languages), the operation is completed first, then the assignment. That means you can do this:

```
Market.Bank = Market.Bank - GE.Price;
```

Conceptually:

1. take the current value of `Market.Bank`, subtract the current value of `GE.Price` and store that in a temporary location
2. Set the value of `Market.Bank` to the value from the temporary location

This is a fundamental concept in programming, but for anyone who has been programming for more than a very short time is easy to forget that this is something that had to be learned. Once you've got the concept you won't even think about it as you are writing code. It will become almost automatic.

As others have noted there are `+=` and `-=` operators. They are simply shortcuts for the more explicit statement provided here. I chose not to use them to make it much more explicit what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

To add a variables value to another, type

```
va1 += va2:
```

To substract a variables value from another, type

```
va1 -= va2:
```